# How do I design my database with lots of columns?

Tags: mysql, database, nosql

There will be hundreds of columns and thousands of tuples, each column has a similar meaning, they represent the same kind of thing, such as different universities.
So which database should I take and how to design?
Is Mysql ok ?
Will hundreds of columns be a problem , or should I divide them into tables?
I'm new to database, thanks for any help in advance !

Comment: You will need to be a bit more precise and present work you've did in that direction so far. Since this is a designer task, showing us what you've learned so far (based on research/googling) will be enough as we will not do it for you :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [jonction tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table), as it is the classical answer to the issue you describe.

Basically, the structure you'll get is :

- a "Universities" table, with only the list of the universities.
- a "Departments" table (if you determine the departements for each university, for exemple)
- and a "Universities_Departments" table who will link the previous two, each entry (row) basically saying "This Departments exists in this University"

Answer (score 0):

Yes 100s of columns could be a problem.
Example
Course, University1, University2,... University999

could be described as

```
Course
ID, Name,...

University
Id, Name, ...

CourseUniversity
CourseID
UniversityID
```

Find a database normalisation tutorial, if you are going to go down the sql route.